# Difference between $LOGNAME and logname

Tags: environment-variables

When the `echo $LOGNAME` and `logname` commands run normally, I get identical results from them:

```
pandya@pandya-desktop:~$ echo $LOGNAME
pandya
pandya@pandya-desktop:~$ logname
pandya
```

Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [Environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables):

`$LOGNAME` is same as `$USER` which gives

> The name of the currently logged-in user. This variable is set by the
> system. You probably shouldn't change its value manually.

From `man logname`:

> logname - print user´s login name

---

Explained **differently used** by following example:

```
pandya@pandya-desktop:~$ sudo su
root@pandya-desktop:/home/pandya# echo $LOGNAME
root
root@pandya-desktop:/home/pandya# logname
pandya
root@pandya-desktop:/home/pandya# exit
exit
pandya@pandya-desktop:~$
```

---

Here you can see the difference after logging as root in a terminal,

- `$LOGNAME` gives the name of the currently **logged-in user in the terminal (i.e `root`)**
- Whereas `logname` prints the user's login name who **logged in to the session (i.e. `pandya`)**

Comment: Thanks. Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446545/logname-no-login-name

Answer (score 7):

The utility logname is broken in 16.04, apparently on purpose because it's possible to hack the value it returns, which could be a security flaw. 
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747046
I had been using logname in some scripts, and found it useful because it always returned the same value (my login name) whether I was calling it from from a my own level or from a sudo invocation, whereas the environment variables $USER and $LOGNAME do not. I wasn't worried about someone hacking into my computer and modifying the value it returns. Alas.... I have found a workaround. I created a file in my home directory as such

```
echo $USER > ~/.logname
```

When I want to access my logname (e.g., assigning to a Bash variable g_logname), I do so thusly:

```
declare g_logname="$(<~/.logname)";
```

This works for me, whether as myself or at the root level through sudo, which maintains the assignment of "~" as my home directory. I can create a .logname file for the home directory of each user on the system. Yes, someone could hack into my computer and change these files, but I'm not really worried about that. I just want my scripts to work.