# Test -s is failing

Tags: bash, scripts, mysql

Help,
I am running Ubuntu 23.10 Server and trying to write a script to back up my server. As the script runs it should create an archive and then check for the archive's existence. The relevant code is.

```bash
ROOTNAME="/mnt/backup/"\`date +"%Y%m%d"\`

SQLNAME=$ROOTNAME"mysql.sql"

mysqldump -h localhost -u root -pabcd123 --skip-tz-utc -A --add-drop-database --databases > "$SQLNAME" 2> /dev/null

if [ -s $SQLNAME ]
then
echo \`date "+%H:%M:%S~%d/$n/%Y"\` " SQL Dumped successfully" >> "$LOGNAME"
else
echo \`date "+%H:%M:%S~%d/$n/%Y"\` " ERROR: SQL Dump Not found exiting...." >> "$LOGNAME"
    exit 1
fi
```

The file generated by the mysqldump statement is being successfully created. However, the `if [ test ]; then` statement is not working neither the success nor failure branch of the statement is being followed and I am getting no output to my log file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are those `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` and `<BR>` charachters I just edited out added by you in the question for styling purpose or you have copied them from your script file and they actually exist there? ... And is the path to your log file defined somewhere in the script i.e. the definition of `"$LOGNAME"` doesn't appear in your added script snippet.

Comment: ... and why do you escape the backticks for command substitution with a backslash? ... Have you initially copied the script from a website in the browser and pasted to a file then ran it?

Comment: You should avoid ALLCAPS variable names for shell variables and here **particularly** avoid `LOGNAME` (which is an environment variable that should contain the user's login name). It's **far** more likely that `$LOGNAME` isn't expanding to what you expect than that a simple conditional expression should execute neither branch...

Comment: ... Please see [`$LOGNAME`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490620/difference-between-logname-and-logname)

Answer (score 1):

Running the line in your script -

```
ROOTNAME="/mnt/backup/"\`date +"%Y%m%d"\` ; echo $ROOTNAME
```

results in:

```
+%Y%m%d`: command not found
```

Perhaps this would be a better way to define your `ROOTNAME` variable:

```
ROOTNAME="/mnt/backup/`date '+%Y%m%d'`"
```

Running:

```
ROOTNAME="/mnt/backup/`date '+%Y%m%d'`" ; echo $ROOTNAME
```

results in:

```
/mnt/backup/20231120
```

Using `bash -x ./yourscript` or `sh -x ./yourscript` is a very useful tool for diagnosing problems and debugging shell scripts. Invoking a bash or sh shell with the `-x` option causes each shell command in your script to be printed before it is executed and displays the result of each command in your script.

It is best practice to enclose variables in quotes - `if [ -s "$SQLNAME" ]`

Also, You should avoid using ALLCAPS in variable names, as recommended by [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) in [This comment](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1493332/timeline#comment_2616329) Below your question.

Kudos to [Raffa](https://askubuntu.com/users/968501/raffa) for encouraging me to re-evaluate my original answer!

Comment: Although quoting is good practice, I don't think this is the culprit though ... after all the path and filename resulting from the expansion of `$SQLNAME` appear to be a simple `/mnt/backup/3482456mysql.sql` so should be parsed right anyway.

Comment: @Raffa You were correct! After looking deeper into the OP script, I found a error with ROOTNAME variable and updated my answer.

Comment: Might be worth noting as well that the usage of `$(...)` notation for command substitution instead of legacy backticks `\`...\`` is encouraged ... Please see https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2006

Comment: Thank you Guys I have managed to solve this problem now.